# Where is Diagnostics & Usage Data stored on iOS?

Tags: iphone, crash, logs

Since I've installed a few jailbreak tweaks, my iPhone has been crashing fairly regularly and I would like to know exactly what's causing it.

Does anyone know the direct path to where the crash logs/reports are stored on the device (`/var/mobile/`, for example)? This way I can clear all current logs, to start afresh, and I can extract them for viewing on a bigger screen, etc. Or does anyone know of a more advanced way to interact with and analyse the iPhone's Diagnostics & Usage data, in general?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official logs and crash logs in on the path
`/var/mobile/Library/Logs`. 
You can also download `syslog`. And get his logs from `/var/syslog`

Answer (score 1):

[Crash Reporter](http://code.google.com/p/networkpx/wiki/Using_CrashReporter) is a convenient tool for viewing recent crash reports on a jailbroken device - it's a free package hosted by BigBoss repository.

You can also view your syslog on the device by installing `syslog > /var/log/syslog` (a free package hosted by Cydia/Telesphoreo repository), rebooting your device, and then using your favorite tool to view it at the command line ([see here for slightly more detailed instructions](http://www.jailbreakqa.com/questions/32462/frequently-asked-questions#81925)). The `syslog` records where each crash report is saved.

Comment: Is there nothing for the desktop? It would be preferable and more convenient if I could interact with the reports from the desktop. Bigger screen, windows, and all that.. Or do I use the syslogs to find where they are and then extract them to the desktop?

Comment: I would suggest copying your syslog to your desktop and then also copying the crash reports too. OpenSSH on the device + a desktop SFTP client (like Transmit or Cyberduck) can make this easier.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But, as I said in my question, I need to path to the reports and logs.